# Using store data in Component pulls in default values, instead of updated ones

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new to Vue, and am trying to use data from a store in a component. This data gets set when the app loads, and I have confirmed that it is getting set properly.

However, when I try to access this data from the store in a component (I'm using mapState), all I get are the default values for the store, and not the data that was set.

The store I am trying to access is:

```
       //user.js 
      const defaults = {
        emailAddress: '',
        gender: 'N/A',
        registered: false,
        userName: '',
      };

    const state = {
      user: { ...defaults, },
    };

    const getters = {};

    const actions = {
      login ({ commit, }) {
        api.post(/loginurl).then((response) => {
          commit('setUserInfo', { ...defaults, ...response, });
        });
      },
    };

    const mutations = {
      setUserInfo (state, user) {
        state.user = {...state, ...user,};
      },
    };

    const user = {
      namespaced: true,
      state,
      getters,
      actions,
      mutations,
    };
    export default user;
```

I've confirmed that all data is getting set correctly in setUserInfo.

However, when I access this in a component like so:

```
<template>
 <div class="user-info">
    <p> {{ user }} </p>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('user', { user: (state) => state.user, },),
  }
};
</script>
```

All the defaults for user print out in my template, instead of the values that were set in 'setUserInfo.

I will also add, that if I just try to access this via a computed property directly, I also get the defaults. For example:

```
userInfo () {
  return this.$store.state.user;
},
```

Will also just return the defaults.

Do I need to set up a getter in the store, and then just use that in my component instead? Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: very odd ... try, instead of mapState, use mapGetters and write a getter for what you need

Comment: The same thing happens if I use a getter....it returns a default value.

Comment: what if you change this "state.user = {...state, ...user,};" to this "state.user = {...user};"

Comment: Same issue, for some reason. It's so odd. THe user info gets set correctly on the home page. But when I nav to a different page (one that uses that component), any attempt to access the state gives me the defaults.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening in your case but I'd suggest the Vue-devtools for Chrome. There you can see a list of all changes made in the store, which should help you with finding the problem.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: try changing userInfo(){return this.$store.state.user.user;}

Comment: Yeah, I have the dev tools. When I check the user object in vuex bindings, it just displays the default values.

Comment: and using this.$store.state.user.user still returns the default, which is strange, because I would think that should return undefined...

Comment: remove the "...defaults" from the "commit('setUserInfo', { ...defaults, ...response, });". remove "...state" from state.user = {...state, ...user,};.
and put a console.log(user) inside the setUserInfo mutation and see what it reads

Comment: "this.$store.state.user.user still returns the default" - I think you are somehow putting a copy of the store into store.user, and then again putting a copy of the store into store.user.store.user

Comment: Could you add an example of what `response` contains to the question? If the relevant user fields aren't directly in that object then the behaviour you've described is to be expected.